# Does C++ have anything like List<string> in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

Does C++ has anything like `List<>` in C#? Something like `List<string>` for storing an array of strings.

Comment: Note that "generics" are generally referred to as "templates" in C++. The standard template library provides a number of containers other than lists, too, if you ever need them.

Comment: though there is `std::list<std::string>` you probably will want to use `std::vector`, or if it's static `std::array`

Comment: @Nawaz:  The .NET `List<T>` provides constant-time access to elements by index, much like `std::vector` and very much unlike `std::list`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is actually

```
std::vector<std::string>
```

`std::list` is a linked list, not an array like C#'s `List<T>` class.

E.g.

```
#include <iostream> // iostream is for cout and endl; not necessary just to use vector or string
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> list;
    list.push_back("foo");
    list.push_back("bar");
    for( vector<string>::const_iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it )
        cout << *it << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `std::list` class is actually equivalent to C#'s `LinkedList<T>` class.

Comment: vector is  not in vs , what header should I use ?

Comment: You need to `#include <vector>` and `#include <string>` (for `std::string`). Additionally, you need to explicitly qualify the types as `std::vector<std::string>` unless you do `using namespace std;` at the top of your C++ file.

Comment: @Ata:  You need to take a step back, get [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and learn to program in C++ correctly, from the ground up.  It is very difficult to learn C++ by trying to adapt code and idioms you are familiar with from other languages, and it is very easy to write horribly incorrect C++ code if you haven't learned to write C++ correctly.

Comment: I agree with James's sentiment. You seem to be lacking some fundamental knowledge about the differences between C++ and C#.

Answer (score 7):

A List in .NET is not a linked list. The data structure you are looking for is a resizeable array.

```
std::vector<std::string> list;
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ has `std::vector` template class that corresponds to C#'s `List`. It also has `std::list` template that corresponds to C# `SingleLinkedList`.

One must be prepared that in C++ `vector` and `list` call copy constructor of item. So, for each string you have a copy will be created.

So, if you are limited on memory or if you want to store the same strings in multiple collections, you'd better use `std::vector<std::string*>` or `std::vector<char*>` instead of `std::vector<string>`.

Comment: `std::list` is a doubly-linked-list, not a singly-linked-list.

Comment: Sure, but BCL hasn't double-linked list and STL hasn't single-linked one. What I meant is existing classes are similar in terms of guaranteed insertion/deletion time. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: It is ill-advised to have a container of pointers as such a thing is inherently not exception safe.  In most circumstances, such a thing is not necessary anyway, and where such a thing might be necessary there are almost always far better solutions.